# Grafana Cloud: dividing two queries shows "no data"

Tags: grafana, promql, grafana-templating

In a Grafana dashboard panel, I have two queries:

```
rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{cloud=~"${cloud}",environment=~"${environment}",location=~"${location}",container="tlm-telemetry-service",namespace="tlm"}[5m])
```

and

```
avg(kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores{namespace="tlm"})
```

which can be shown well separately:
[image]

But when I try to use the "avg" one to divide the "rate" one:

```
rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{cloud=~"${cloud}",environment=~"${environment}",location=~"${location}",container="tlm-telemetry-service",namespace="tlm"}[5m])/avg(kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores{namespace="tlm"})
```

the result shows "no data".
[image]

This query used to work in Grafana Version 6.7.5, but when I tried to move it to Grafana Cloud, this problem happened.

Any one has any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This throws a `No data` because you have two different expression data types. On the left side, you have a `range vector` and the right side `scalar` type. The query should return the same LabelSet in each part, so you need to group the right side also with the `by` clause.

E.g. the following query should work:

```sh
sum by (namespace,container) (rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{cloud=~"${cloud}",environment=~"${environment}",location=~"${location}",container="tlm-telemetry-service",namespace="tlm"}[5m])) / 
avg by (namespace,container) (kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores{namespace="tlm"})
```